# how to merge two json array of objects and display in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop

How can i merge this Data & display in table with map in react? Text in First Column & Count in Second

```
const  handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let URL1 = "https://herokuapp.com"
    let URL2 = "https://appspot.com"
    
    const promise1 = await axios.post(URL1, inputValue , {headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' , 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}});
    const promise2 = await axios.post(URL2, inputValue , {headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000' , 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}});
    
    Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(values) {
      
      setDataOne1(values[0].data);
      setDataOne2(values[1].data);
      
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })

    }
```

Json Data First

```
{text: 'best movies'}
```

Json Data 2nd

```
{count: '12345'}
```

Comment: You can merge them with spread syntax. `setData({...values[0].data, ...values[1].data});`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `Object.assign` or spread operator:

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(values) {
  let merged = {...values[0].data, ...values[1].data};
  let mergedByAssign = Object.assign(values[0].data, values[1].data);

  setDataOne1(values[0].data);
  setDataOne2(values[1].data);
  
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
})
```